# How to unhide folders in Intellij IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, directory, hidden

I have an "src" folder that contains the "main" and "test" folders. In File Explorer, the "test" folder is not hidden. However, this "test" folder is hidden in the Intellij.

The solutions I've tried out are
1. "show excluded file" checked
2. file/ setting/ file type/ ignore files and folder; I emptied all kinds of files under ignore files and folder

Nothing changed.
Thanks in advance if you know what causes it.

Comment: Make sure Project scope is set in Project view: https://i.imgur.com/v8I70v0.png

Comment: Thank you! Now I am able to see my test folder. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Project scope is set in Project view:
[image]